# Qt IDE doesn't show output

Tags: c++, qt

When i try to get my application output on terminal,It's get faile and don't show any things to me.
I am trying to change default terminal ,But problem not sloved!

Any idea?

My Qt version :

> Qt Creator 2.5.2  Based on Qt 4.8.2 (32 bit)

Comment: Strange, I've never had problems with Qt outputting to terminal, be that using `std::cout`, `QTextStream` or even `qDebug`... Are you sure your entire toolchain is properly installed and operational?

Comment: Sometimes in Qt console applications there is a few seconds of delay/lag before console output is displayed, I don't know why exactly is that, but it seems Qt launches a modified console view, because selecting with mouse does not work too.

Comment: Yes, Toolchain is installed truely and working fine  ,I should add this notice I am using ubuntu 12.10 .

Comment: Can you try "qDebug()<<"Test Output";, on Main() function, before "exec()" function call ?.

Comment: @olive : Yes,But the problem is remaining.

Comment: What is the failure comments on Application output?

Comment: @Olive : Nothing.Just empty screen!

Comment: Can you update the code with pro file settings for more info?